# Using a loop to create an accordion - Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, velocity

I'm trying to loop through fields to create an accordion. It's getting the information and returning it correctly. Only issue is that when a panel is clicked, the other open one doesn't collapse. Any ideas how to fix this?

[image: Click Here for the resulting display]

```
        #elseif ($column.getChild("features").value == "Accordion" )
            #set ( $accordions = $_XPathTool.selectNodes($column, "accordion") )
            #set ( $accHeading  = $column.getChild("accHeading").value )      

            <h2>$_SerializerTool.serialize($column.getChild("accHeading"), true)</h2>
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordian">
                <div class="panel panel-default">      

            #foreach ( $accordion in $accordions )
                #set ( $accTitle = $accordion.getChild("accTitle").value )
                #set ( $accContent = $accordion.getChild("accContent").value )

                    <div class="panel-heading">      
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse${foreach.index}">${accTitle}</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                        <div id="collapse${foreach.index}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">${accContent}</div>
                        </div>
            #end
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you've looked at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion ?

Comment: can you put this in a jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 2):

you have the `<div class="panel panel-default">` added outside of the loop, this should be inside the foreach since it has multiple panels. Have a look at the correct Bootstrap accordion structure: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: I tried that at the beginning and it doesn't work unfortunately. Still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can find easiest way [here](https://www.plus2net.com/jquery/msg-demo/accordion-active-collapse-all.php)

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<div id='accordion' class='accordion'>
 <h3>Header 1 ( panel No. 0 )</h3>
  <div>
    Text about Header 1    
  </div>
 <h3>Header 2 ( panel No. 1 )</h3>
  <div>
    Text about Header 2    
  </div>
<h3>Header 3 ( panel No. 2 )</h3> 
  <div>
    Text header 3
  </div>
<h3>Header 4 ( panel No. 3 )</h3>
  <div>
    Text about Header 4.
   </div>
</div>

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<link href='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$( '#accordion' ).accordion({
active: false,
collapsible: true
});

})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```